# How to Create Mapping for join entity from DTOs using Automapper

Tags: automapper

I have the following code snippet. 
I wish to save my User entity after mapping along with related entities as a single transaction. i.e. Entity framework will update the UserBranchSpecialism Table with the generated UserId as expected.
I can't find a way of specifying the User property of the UserBranchSpecialism as part of my mapping configuration.

```
// ENTITIES
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BranchProfile BranchProfile { get;set; }
}

public class BranchProfile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<UserBranchSpecialism> Specialisms { get; set; }
}

public class BranchSpecialism
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserBranchSpecialism
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public BranchSpecialism BranchSpecialism { get;set; }
    public int BranchSpecialismId { get;set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

// DTOS
public class UserCreateDto 
{
    public string Name { get;set; }
}
public class BranchProfileDto
{
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public List<int> BranchSpecialismIds { get;set; }
}

// MAPPING CONFIG
CreateMap<UserCreateDto, User>();
CreateMap<BranchProfileDto, BranchProfile>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Specialisms, 
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.BranchSpecialismIds
                    .Select(id => new UserBranchSpecialism() { BranchSpecialismId = id }).ToList()));
```

Ideally,
I will like to do something like this:

```
// MAPPING CONFIG
CreateMap<UserCreateDto, User>();
CreateMap<BranchProfileDto, BranchProfile>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Specialisms, 
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.BranchSpecialismIds
                    .Select(id => new UserBranchSpecialism() { BranchSpecialismId = id, User = ????  }).ToList()));
```

How can i achieve this with the mappings split out as above or using any other alternative means?
Thanks in advance.